# Produce table output for summary statistic

Tags: r, rbind

I'm running a loop to retrieve the mode of a column in R according to a condition. Once the mode is calculated, I would like to append it to a matrix (or data frame) with the name of the condition attached.

In my attempt, however, it assigns the word 'label' to the resulting mode, i.e., label = 9. How would I correct this such that instead of saying, e.g., label = 9, it says "blues" = 9, with "blues" being the name of the label in this case?

```
clusters <- NULL
# Loop over each genre label, return mode for each
for (label in unique(music$label)) {
  mode <- getmode(music$cluster[music$label == label])
  clusters <- rbind(clusters, label = mode)
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the desired output? I don't exactly understand what you're asking, but base R provides the aggregate() function for creating summary statistics by group. You shouldn't need to build up a data structure in a for loop

Comment: @BillO'Brien the desired output would be a matrix with each rows corresponding to a unique genre of music ('label') and a column giving the statistical mode of the clusters to which tracks of that genre belong (after performing cluster analysis). Sorry if I haven't explained it well.

Since your comment about not needing a for loop, I actually turned to tidyverse and achieved what I wanted using group_by and summarise. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @BillO'Brien, base R's `aggregate` can work as well:

```r
aggregate(cbind(mode=cluster) ~ label, music, FUN=getmode)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved without using a loop as per [@bill-obrien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4950439/bill-obrien)'s comment. Using 'group_by' in tidyverse to group by the unique labels in the column, and then for each unique label, found the statistical mode of the second column ('cluster'), which is returned in a tibble - a data frame format.

```
music %>% group_by(label) %>%
  summarise(mode = getmode(music$cluster[music$label == label]))
```

Comment: Do you really need `music$label == label` given the grouping?

Comment: Yes but only because that's how the `getmode` function works. Removing `music$label == label` just returns the mode for the entire `music$cluster` column

Comment: Simply replace ending with `summarise(mode=getmode(cluster))` without calling whole vector `music$cluster`. (This would be equivalent to `aggregate` solution.)

Comment: I see, I understand now. Thank you